# How to resolve "dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python-apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu9_all.deb"?

Tags: dpkg

Update Manager will not update even though I have over 100 updates to install. I get a error message like this:

```
installArchives() failed: 
Extracting templates from packages: 29%%
Extracting templates from packages: 58%%
Extracting templates from packages: 88%%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%%
Preconfiguring packages ...

Extracting templates from packages: 29%%
Extracting templates from packages: 58%%
Extracting templates from packages: 88%%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%%
Preconfiguring packages ...

Extracting templates from packages: 29%%
Extracting templates from packages: 58%%
Extracting templates from packages: 88%%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%%
Preconfiguring packages ...

Extracting templates from packages: 29%%
Extracting templates from packages: 58%%
Extracting templates from packages: 88%%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 189751 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace python-problem-report 2.0.1-0ubuntu7 (using .../python-problem-report_2.0.1-0ubuntu9_all.deb) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 33, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 33, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python-problem-report_2.0.1-0ubuntu9_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 39, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to replace python-apport 2.0.1-0ubuntu7 (using .../python-apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu9_all.deb) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 33, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 33, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python-apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu9_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 39, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to replace apport 2.0.1-0ubuntu7 (using .../apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu9_all.deb) ...
apport stop/waiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 33, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 33, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu9_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
apport start/running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 39, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to replace gnome-orca 3.4.1-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../gnome-orca_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.1_all.deb) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 33, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 33, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-orca_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 39, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to replace python-piston-mini-client 0.7.2-0ubuntu1 (using .../python-piston-mini-client_0.7.2+bzr57-0ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 33, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 33, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python-piston-mini-client_0.7.2+bzr57-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 39, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to replace oneconf 0.2.8 (using .../oneconf_0.2.8.1_all.deb) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 33, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 33, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/oneconf_0.2.8.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 39, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to replace software-center 5.2.2 (using .../software-center_5.2.2.2_all.deb) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 33, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 33, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/software-center_5.2.2.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 39, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to replace libglade2-0 1:2.6.4-1ubuntu1 (using .../libglade2-0_1%%3a2.6.4-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libglade2-0 ...
Preparing to replace libv4l-0 0.8.6-1ubuntu1 (using .../libv4l-0_0.8.6-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb) ...
De-configuring libv4l-0:i386 ...
Unpacking replacement libv4l-0 ...
Preparing to replace libv4l-0:i386 0.8.6-1ubuntu1 (using .../libv4l-0_0.8.6-1ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libv4l-0:i386 ...
Preparing to replace libv4lconvert0:i386 0.8.6-1ubuntu1 (using .../libv4lconvert0_0.8.6-1ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
De-configuring libv4lconvert0 ...
Unpacking replacement libv4lconvert0:i386 ...
Preparing to replace libv4lconvert0 0.8.6-1ubuntu1 (using .../libv4lconvert0_0.8.6-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libv4lconvert0 ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-problem-report_2.0.1-0ubuntu9_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu9_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu9_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-orca_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-piston-mini-client_0.7.2+bzr57-0ubuntu1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/oneconf_0.2.8.1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/software-center_5.2.2.2_all.deb
Error in function: 
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Setting up libglade2-0 (1:2.6.4-1ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing gnome-orca (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: error processing python-problem-report (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
Setting up libv4lconvert0 (0.8.6-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libv4lconvert0:i386 (0.8.6-1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing python-piston-mini-client (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
Setting up libv4l-0 (0.8.6-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libv4l-0:i386 (0.8.6-1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-apport:
 python-apport depends on python-problem-report (>= 0.94); however:
  Package python-problem-report is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-apport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-center:
 software-center depends on python-piston-mini-client (>= 0.1+bzr29); however:
  Package python-piston-mini-client is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing software-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oneconf:
 oneconf depends on python-piston-mini-client (>= 0.3+bzr32-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package python-piston-mini-client is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing oneconf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport:
 apport depends on python-apport (>= 2.0.1-0ubuntu7); however:
  Package python-apport is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing apport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

This has been going on for two weeks now and I cannot get any updates. Any help would be great.

Comment: Please add 4 spaces before each line of 'output'.  Please confirm which **Ubuntu** version.

Comment: @david6 Looks like he is using 12.04. Unless he is using Precise packages in Oneiric or other release version. (cue: gnome-orca version is 3.4 among others)

Comment: I tried editing the title to be more specific and took the freedom to add in a 12.04 tag. If any of you disagree, feel free to edit accordingly.

Comment: The python-problem-report version is part of a precise apport SRU release June 4.

Answer (score 137):

You need to force overwriting of the files causing the errors:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite <filename>
```

In your case it's going to be:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/python-problem-report_2.0.1-0ubuntu9_all.deb
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Source: http://www.absolutelytech.com/2010/06/30/solved-error-dpkg-error-processing-filename-unpack-trying-to-overwrite/

Comment: I was having similar issues with getting an overriding problem error and running sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite <filename> fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: +1 i was facing this issue of wine in my ubuntu16.04 OS from a long time. its resolved now. thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: +1 This stops lxqt daily ppa complaining about my abuses.

Comment: +1 I had the same issue with wireless-regdb package and that helped.

Comment: This worked like a charm for mee too. Thank you.

Comment: I had similar issue when ubuntu was trying to update `containers-common` package. Following this steps resolved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 46):

You can try the following command:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you still end up with the same error, try:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Even if that doesn't work and you still get the same error, check back and we can sort this out.

Comment: I had a similar problem with E:Problem renaming the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin.random chars. Tried the first approach and that worked famouisly.

Comment: This had no effect for me.  I still get a ton of errors like "dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of *"

Comment: What does `sudo dpkg --configure -a` this mean?

Answer (score 5):

It might be a bug in the python-problem-report package or python-minimal package or a bad copy of the package.

I see that this is package from precise-proposed. You may wish to delete this repository from your software sources list and execute `apt-get update` from a terminal session (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) to recover.

You can also try deleting `python-problem-report_2.0.1-0ubuntu9_all.deb` from `/var/cache/apt/archives` so `apt-get upgrade` will have to download a fresh copy again. In the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) type:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/python-problem-report_2.0.1-0ubuntu9_all.deb
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

to erase all of the downloaded files in your cache.

Try the upgrade again.

If neither of these help you should leave a comment at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/984944 describing your experience in using this proposed package, or once the package is generally release, file a bug against the apport package.

- [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

I've left one comment about this question at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/984944 but you should add a comment describing the steps you have gone through and the output from apt-get upgrade from above.

Comment: While you are right on the money that it probably is a bug in `python-problem-report`, I am not comfortable recommending the `sudo rm` command. That should definitely be the last resort. Good job otherwise!

Comment: So long as the `sudo rm ...` command is not mistyped it should be fine and needn't be considered a last resort: files in `/var/cache/apt/archives` are just archived (i.e., left over) package files. As John S Gruber says, the somewhat commonly recommended `sudo apt-get clean` command deletes *all* those files. Deleting a cached .deb file is a safe and effective way of ensuring a new (and hopefully uncorrupted) .deb must be downloaded next time the package is installed (or reinstalled).

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

```
  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.5   2         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python2.7   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.5   2         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Select option python2.7.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you might try removing the package and adding it afterwards. This worked for me on the Citrix client. Be careful about what you're removing (of course).

```
sudo apt-get remove icaclient:i386
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem on a system which had both python 2.7 and python 3.4 installed. The problem was a compatibility issue with the package **python-subversion**, which apparently only works with python 2 due to a change in [ConfigParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser). I addressed it by doing

```
ls -la /usr/bin | grep python
```

To confirm that the **python** executable on my path was a symlink to python 3. Then

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

To use python 2 instead. After that apt-get was able to complete normally, and I reverted my symlink change.

```
rm -f /usr/bin/python
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: The last 2 commands can be replaced by `ln -rs /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python`. Also, if you already have another symlink `/usr/bin/python3` pointing to the latest `python3` release, as it usually happens, you can make another step forward with `ln -rs /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`. Anyway, thanks for the solution, it worked for me after a problem in the `mercurial` installation.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
mount -t proc proc /proc
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Can you add an explanation on why this is a solution?