# software center issues

Tags: 12.10, software-center

It says items cannot be installed or removed until the package catalog is repaired. Do you want to repair it now? I'm new to Ubuntu and have gone through various answers on this forum and so far, nothing I have tried has worked. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try http://askubuntu.com/a/148389/9025 ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds like a Broken Packages issue. Maybe you can install Synaptic (`sudo apt-get install synaptic` in a terminal) and give a chance to the workaround provided [right here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto#How_to_fix_broken_packages) in order to fix your broken packages.

From the site:

> ## How to fix broken packages
>
> **'Broken packages'** are packages that have unsatisfied dependencies. If broken packages are detected, Synaptic will not allow any further
>   changes to the system until all broken packages have been fixed.
>
> ### To fix broken packages
>
> (Inside of Synaptic, usually opened with administrative privileges with `gksudo synaptic`)
>   Choose Edit > Fix Broken Packages from the menu.
>
> Choose Apply Marked Changes from the Edit menu or press Ctrl + P.
>
> Confirm the summary of changes and click Apply.
>
> If that does not help, then please follow this procedure:
>
> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure

It worked for me a couple of times, you give this a try and let us know if this solves your issue.

Good luck!