# Getting error while installing python-kivy packages in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg

I'm not able to install python-kivy, I got this error:

```
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Processing triggers for libreoffice-common ...

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/update-manager-core_1%3a0.156.14.15_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/update-manager_1%3a0.156.14.15_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-uno_1%3a3.5.7-0ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-ubuntuone-client_3.0.2-0ubuntu2.2_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-libxml2_2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.9_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-lxml_2.3.2-1_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: how did you install it?

Comment: kivy is a beast to get working on ubuntu mostly.  It's a beast of a solution, and I like it a lot... It's too troublesome to use OOTB though.

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-kivy,  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-kivy

Answer (score 1):

you need to force overwriting the packages this problem comes with repositories

`sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite <filename>`

and then run dpkg

`sudo apt-get -f install`

see [this](http://www.absolutelytech.com/2010/06/30/solved-error-dpkg-error-processing-filename-unpack-trying-to-overwrite/) for more help on dpkg and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148383/how-to-resolve-dpkg-error-processing-var-cache-apt-archives-python-apport-2-0) for more help on this error

Comment: Have you tried this?. Why do you know that it needs forve-overwrite?. The problem looks different than those on your links to me.