# Trying to fix broken dependencies (Libre Office)

Tags: apt, dependencies, libreoffice

I uninstalled Libreoffice and installed Openoffice only To find out that I do not like OpenOffice any more. I uninstalled OpenOffice today and tried installing LibreOffice and I got errors.

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:4.2.7) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-help-en-us : Depends: libreoffice-l10n-en-us
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-za : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 y-ppa-manager : Depends: yad (>= 0.8.0) but it is not installed
                 Depends: python-software-properties but it is not installed
```

So I tried to do `sudo apt-get -f install`
 and I get asked to install and I say yes this is the message.

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-crystal libreoffice-style-hicontrast
  libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-style-sifr libreoffice-style-tango
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
41 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/19.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 76.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 453874 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.7-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:4.2.7-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.7-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1-9764
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/program/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.10.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.7-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can no longer install anything or update my system.

Comment: More information is needed, like what version of Ubuntu you are using, and whether or not you are using a ppa.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, I initally tried installing Libreoffice through the App grid Software

Comment: You need to see this..https://askubuntu.com/questions/691630/libreoffice-core-dependency-in-every-install I was having the same problem..
It helped me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have answered this myself after doing some research and learning some new tricks.  I am going to provide the answer in case someone runs into an issue related to these broken dependencies. I used synaptic package manager to remove broken packages. Here is how I did that

First I Downloaded Synaptic Package Manager [Synaptic Package Manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=synaptic)

I then moved the downloaded .deb file to my home folder ( for easy terminal access) then proceeded to open terminal

```
CTRL + ALT + T
```

I had to install the package via dpkg because apt-get was not working due to broken dependencies

```
sudo dpkg -i synaptic_0.81.1_amd64.deb
```

once this was complete I opened up synaptic running the following in terminal

```
sudo synaptic
```

Within the Synaptic Package Manager

click on the `Status Tab`

and then click on `Broken` and select the packages that are broken.
 and `Mark for Complete Removal` and continue to apply the changes.

I also made sure everything was completely removed by using the following in terminal

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and double checking the packages in synaptic package manager

there was no left over libre office packages  so I continued to install Libre Office through Ubuntu Software Center

Answer (score 4):

If you have this problem do this:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/bin/soffice
sudo apt-get -f install -y
```

Comment: Thanks this works for me, Ubuntu run on Android termux.

Answer (score 4):

I understand this happened years ago, but I had a similar situation with 18.04 LTS (Bionic).  My computer was stuck, not updates, installs...nothing.  So......

The only way I solved the problem was by installing the package named libreoffice-common. This is where I found the dpkg error message displaying:

**dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a6.0.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1.4-9788
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/program/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a6.0.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"**

I had to carefully read the error message.  It was letting me know that another application by the name of openoffice-debian-menus was using the file 
located in /usr/bin/soffice. This file could not be overwritten for some reason or another.

So I removed the program using dpkg:
sudo dpkg -P openoffice-debian-menus 4.1.4-9788

Installed libreoffice-common:
sudo apt install libreoffice-common

Ran updates:
sudo apt update && sudo apt list --upgradable

After running the previous command, use the following to verify that you want the packages included in the upgrade: sudo apt show pkgs "Package name".  If everything looks fine, run sudo apt full-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove.

I hope everything pans out.

Answer (score 0):

Try these, one by one:

```
sudo apt-get purge openoffice*
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.7-0ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo ap-get install libreoffice
```

source: [How to resolve "dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python-apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu9_all.deb"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148383/how-to-resolve-dpkg-error-processing-var-cache-apt-archives-python-apport-2-0)