# How do I resolve "error processing archive" when trying to upgrade Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I am trying to do an upgrade on Ubuntu 14.04. I run:

```
sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
```

When I run that, I get this error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic_3.13.0-24.47~precise2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
```

Here's the entire output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/52.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 155 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 63480 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic_3.13.0-24.47~precise2_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic (3.13.0-24.47~precise2) over (3.13.0-24.46) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic_3.13.0-24.47~precise2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/mm/hwpoison-inject.ko', which is also in package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic 3.13.0-24.46
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic_3.13.0-24.47~precise2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/148383/how-to-resolve-dpkg-error-processing-var-cache-apt-archives-python-apport-2-0

Comment: @Rinzwind The second answer in your link: `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite <filename>` fixed it. Thanks!