# Unable to fix ubuntu package issue

Tags: 16.04

I am trying to fix the broken packages problem in my ubuntu pc.

when I try to audit my dpkg in terminal (sudo dpkg --audit
) I get....

```
The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
that depend on them) to function properly:

 apport               automatically generate crash reports for debugging

 libglib2.0-dev       Development files for the GLib library
```

---

```
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:

 appgrid              Discover and install apps for Ubuntu

mysql-server         MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the lates

 mysql-workbench-community MySQL Workbench

 python-ecdsa         ECDSA cryptographic signature library (Python 2)

 python-paramiko      Make ssh v2 connections with Python (Python 2)
```

---

```
The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:

 mysql-server-5.7     MySQL database server binaries and system database setup

 python-mysql.connector pure Python implementation of MySQL Client/Server proto

 python-mysqldb       Python interface to MySQL

 python-ptyprocess    Run a subprocess in a pseudo terminal from Python 2

 python-pysqlite2     Python interface to SQLite 3

 python-six           Python 2 and 3 compatibility library (Python 2 interface)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the messages already say, try to reinstall them. 
This can easily be done by just running

> sudo apt install --reinstall [package name]

apt will then reinstall the packages, which should lead to dpkg not showing the packages in audit.

Comment: Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-dev_2.48.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-dev_2.48.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit 1

Comment: you should then proceed with [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148383/how-to-resolve-dpkg-error-processing-var-cache-apt-archives-python-apport-2-0)

Comment: Force installation hasn't solved my problem.. returns error again

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:

Answer (score 0):

Finally, my issue resolved

Reason for the issue (I was configured my phython as 3.5 instead of default 2.7). So, it affects libglib2.0

You can try to fix this by :

```
Executing the command ls -l /usr/bin/python and see it's output, if the file /usr/bin/python point to python3.x , then remove the link with the command sudo rm /usr/bin/python and use this one to create a link to python2 sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python. With this, python2.7 will be back as the default python version in your system.
```

And reinstalled broken packages using synaptic package manager. Everything works well now.