# MySQL server problems installing, completely new to Ubuntu. Sorry

Tags: 14.04, mysql

When I try to install this MySQL for my VPS following the guide on the guide at the website https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install it says this:

```
root@CrispKnotty-VM:~# apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  gcc-4.8-base:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gcc-7-base gcc-7-base:i386 libaio1 libmecab2 libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386
  mysql-client mysql-community-client mysql-community-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-7-base gcc-7-base:i386 libaio1 libmecab2 mysql-client
  mysql-community-client mysql-community-server mysql-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386
2 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 693 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/32.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 239 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libaio1 gcc-7-base gcc-7-base:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libstdc++6 libmecab2
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/libaio1_0.3.110-5_amd64.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libaio1_0.3.110-5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-7-base_7.2.0-17_amd64.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-7-base_7.2.0-17_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-7-base_7.2.0-17_i386.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-7-base_7.2.0-17_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libaio1_0.3.110-5_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-7-base_7.2.0-17_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-7-base_7.2.0-17_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and I have absolutely no clue what it means or how I can fix it... Sorry. I couldn't find this anywhere I searched.

EDIT: Tried [this solution](https://forum.armbian.com/topic/3285-dpkg-deb-error-premature-member/?tab=comments#comment-24711), no luck:

```
root@CrispKnotty-VM:~# apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libnuma1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdpkg-perl
Suggested packages:
  debsig-verify debian-keyring gcc c-compiler binutils bzr
The following packages will be upgraded:
  dpkg libdpkg-perl
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 691 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3449 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1311 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libdpkg-perl dpkg
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/libdpkg-perl_1.19.0.4_all.deb'                                    has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdpkg-perl_1.19.0.4_all                                   .deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg_1.19.0.4_amd64.deb' has p                                   remature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg_1.19.0.4_amd64.deb (                                   --unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdpkg-perl_1.19.0.4_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg_1.19.0.4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT: Tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148383/how-to-resolve-dpkg-error-processing-var-cache-apt-archives-python-apport-2-0#answer-266912), no luck:

```
root@CrispKnotty-VM:~# dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libaio1_0.3.110-5_amd64.deb
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/libaio1_0.3.110-5_amd64.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libaio1_0.3.110-5_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libaio1_0.3.110-5_amd64.deb
```

Comment: https://forum.armbian.com/topic/3285-dpkg-deb-error-premature-member/?do=findComment&comment=24711 I found this to be a solution. Could you try this?

Comment: I tried that and it gave the same "Errors were encountered while processing"

Comment: Again, `dpkg` doesn't seem to like hyphens in filenames. Try manually downloading those `.deb` files and replacing the hyphens with underscores. http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=107728#p513503

Comment: I'm not sure how to download the specific ones that I need.

Comment: there may be a solution here `https://askubuntu.com/questions/148383/how-to-resolve-dpkg-error-processing-var-cache-apt-archives-python-apport-2-0` the second answer has worked for me in the past

Comment: Didn't work either...

Comment: This is a bug in dpkg, as been be seen in [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1730627) .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing `MySQL`, install `MariaDB`.

> MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL.

```
$ sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

To start MariaDB

```
$ sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

To enable MariaDB to automatically start at boot time, run

```
$ sudo systemctl enable mariadb
```

Now run the post installation security script

```
$ sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Access the MySQL shell

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```