# 18.04 download incomplete and can't complete it

Tags: gnome, software-installation, upgrade, update-manager, 18.04

I recently upgraded to the 18.04  ubuntu, but the download did not go so well. When it finished my laptop said that it "installed" but with errors.
I have tried the following commands in the terminal, and now I am just going in circles. I have been using Ubuntu for a while but I am at the end of my abilities.

I ran

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then got

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [69.9 kB]
Fetched 69.9 kB in 1s (56.6 kB/s)                             
Reading package lists... Done
```

then nothing. I ran:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and got this:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-keyring-pkcs11 : Breaks: libp11-kit-gnome-keyring (< 3.27.4-2~) but 3.20.1-1ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I ran

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

then it says:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libp11-kit-gnome-keyring_3.28.0.2-1ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:all 3.28.0.2-1ubuntu1 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with libp11-kit-gnome-keyring which has multiple installed instances
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libp11-kit-gnome-keyring_3.28.0.2-1ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried running the software update, and it says I have too many third parties working. I went into settings and left the first four checked, nothing. I unchecked all of them, nothing. This is where ive been going around for a bit.

Comment: After you unchecked the third party repositories, did you rerun the "sudp apt-get update" command before trying the "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" again?

Comment: Try this out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/148383/how-to-resolve-dpkg-error-processing-var-cache-apt-archives-python-apport-2-0

Comment: I did. and All I get is: 
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done    

and then nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem. I tried to remove the libp11-kit-gnome-keyring but there was nothing installed (??). Then I manually downloaded it from: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/i386/libp11-kit-gnome-keyring/download and installed it. After that:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Still a problem. Then:

```
sudo apt remove libp11-kit-gnome-keyring
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Everything ok? I don't really know what I was doing but after that it was ok. Then just regular update + dist-upgrade.