# Error while upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10

Tags: package-management, upgrade, 20.10

do-release-upgrade throws this error

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1piubui5/groovy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1piubui5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1piubui5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2089, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1piubui5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1932, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.updateSourcesList():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1piubui5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 801, in updateSourcesList
    self.sources = SourcesList(matcherPath=self.datadir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 273, in __init__
    self.matcher = SourceEntryMatcher(matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 470, in __init__
    dist = DistInfo(base_dir=matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distinfo.py", line 184, in __init__
    with open(dist_fname) as dist_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1piubui5/Pop.info'
```

Comment: Did you update your system (by running "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt upgrade) before running do-release-upgrade ?

Comment: Yes, I must mention that I have few pop-os repos enabled, I also did dist-upgrade and got this error "Unpacking pop-gnome-initial-setup (3.36.1~1593716052~20.04~e07a263) ...dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/pop-gnome-initial" after that I followed this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/148383/how-to-resolve-dpkg-error-processing-var-cache-apt-archives-python-apport-2-0#266912 and overwrote that file

Comment: Having repositories from other distributions is never a good idea, and is not supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this issue too, but in my case it was looking for `Ubuntu.info`.

My solution is not a solution, but a workaround: pause do-release-upgrade (simply press <kbd>Crlt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in the terminal) during it checks the exisiting repos, look in `/tmp` for the latest `ubuntu-release-upgrader-*` directory and create an empty info file there (`touch /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-*/Pop.info`, or something like this). Finally you can un-pause the release-upgrade process with `fg`.

Comment: Thanks, that was clever.

Comment: Not working at me, but I have the same problem. Help!

Comment: this is a clever workaround but its better to remove the repos and then re-add them after the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Note `/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-*` the star in krisek's comment. There may be several of these folders that need a `Pop.info` or `ubuntu.info` to be put in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the extra repos from your apt configuration before doing the dist-upgrade, then add them after the upgrade but only after checking they are still compatible. if you don't do this its likely you upgrade will break part way through.

list the repositories enabled in your config

```
apt-add-repository -L
```

remove one

```
apt-add-repository -r 'https://repository.url/ubuntu'
```