# Unable to update to Ubuntu 22.04 from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

So I've been trying to update to Ubuntu 22.04 development release but certain errors are coming. Whenever I try to update the following error comes ->

```
abc@ubuntu:~$ update-manager -d 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
authenticate 'jammy.tar.gz' against 'jammy.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'jammy.tar.gz'
No candidate ver:  chromium
No candidate ver:  microsoft-edge-stable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-6ylluso8/jammy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-6ylluso8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-6ylluso8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2038, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-6ylluso8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1881, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.updateSourcesList():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-6ylluso8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 784, in updateSourcesList
    self.sources = SourcesList(matcherPath=self.datadir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 273, in __init__
    self.matcher = SourceEntryMatcher(matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 470, in __init__
    dist = DistInfo(base_dir=matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distinfo.py", line 184, in __init__
    with open(dist_fname) as dist_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-6ylluso8/Ubuntu.info'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 477, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 430, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-6ylluso8/jammy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-6ylluso8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-6ylluso8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2038, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-6ylluso8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1881, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.updateSourcesList():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-6ylluso8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 784, in updateSourcesList
    self.sources = SourcesList(matcherPath=self.datadir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 273, in __init__
    self.matcher = SourceEntryMatcher(matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 470, in __init__
    dist = DistInfo(base_dir=matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distinfo.py", line 184, in __init__
    with open(dist_fname) as dist_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-6ylluso8/Ubuntu.info'
```

Is there any solution to this?
I guess a file named Ubuntu.info is missing.

EDIT:
I was asked to disable 3rd party repos by @vanadium, but the results remained unchanged.

```
abc@ubuntu:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
authenticate 'jammy.tar.gz' against 'jammy.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'jammy.tar.gz'
No candidate ver:  chromium
No candidate ver:  microsoft-edge-stable
No candidate ver:  pipewire-audio-client-libraries
No candidate ver:  pipewire-bin
No candidate ver:  pipewire-media-session
No candidate ver:  pipewire-pulse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-son1yxme/jammy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-son1yxme/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-son1yxme/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2038, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-son1yxme/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1881, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.updateSourcesList():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-son1yxme/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 784, in updateSourcesList
    self.sources = SourcesList(matcherPath=self.datadir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 273, in __init__
    self.matcher = SourceEntryMatcher(matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 470, in __init__
    dist = DistInfo(base_dir=matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distinfo.py", line 184, in __init__
    with open(dist_fname) as dist_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-son1yxme/Ubuntu.info'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 477, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 430, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-son1yxme/jammy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-son1yxme/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-son1yxme/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2038, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-son1yxme/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1881, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.updateSourcesList():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-son1yxme/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 784, in updateSourcesList
    self.sources = SourcesList(matcherPath=self.datadir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 273, in __init__
    self.matcher = SourceEntryMatcher(matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 470, in __init__
    dist = DistInfo(base_dir=matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distinfo.py", line 184, in __init__
    with open(dist_fname) as dist_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-son1yxme/Ubuntu.info'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135827/discussion-on-question-by-krrish-dhaneja-unable-to-update-to-ubuntu-22-04-from-u).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just was surfing through internet and found the solution to this problem, and my Ubuntu 20.04 was successfully upgraded to 22.04.
The solution can be found [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286195/error-while-upgrading-from-ubuntu-20-04-to-20-10)

Instead of a file called “Pop.info”(as given in the answer) make a file called “Ubuntu.info”

Comment: This is awfully close to a link-only answer.  Can you (without stepping on anyone's IP) include some additional details of the fix?

Comment: You have 'pop.info' because you're on PopOS.  PopOS is NOT Ubuntu and not supported here.  (Closed as offtopic)

Comment: @ZeissIkon I mean i guess there is nothing much more to it, just a file named ubuntu.info was missing from the folder which I added during the update process

Comment: @ThomasWard The answer he found was for PopOS, but Krrish has Ubuntu.  He's just trying to make an unsupported upgrade.

Comment: Pop OS just annoying installed itself with a complete BS "Partial Upgrade" suggestions. Following the above two answers managed to at least upgrade me to the newest Ubuntu version - but with much frustration and gnashing of teeth to get things to how they were before this unwanted jig down the upgrade paths.

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this while doing a `do-release-upgrade` manually.  The gui was failing before this.  The workaround answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286195/error-while-upgrading-from-ubuntu-20-04-to-20-10?newreg=74ebe8519e4145bcb14e7896ff30dce3) by MarianD is what solved it for me.  You need to create the Ubuntu.info file in the `/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-*/` folder using `touch`.

for example:
`touch /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-93aizvle/Ubuntu.info`

This can be tricky since it makes a new folder every time you run `do-distribution-upgrade` and it can fail before you have a chance to type in the `touch` command for the newly created folder.  Exciting!  Took me 4 tries.  Remember to capitalize the 'U'.

I have a strong feeling adding a PopOS repo to my system is to blame.  I did it to get a non-snap version of Chromium but all hell broke loose as a result.  I tried to undo the damage but two years later I still run across some scars. I see a reference to `Pop.info` in many of the answers to this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `do-release-upgrade`?