# Unable to install libgl1-mesa-dri

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, updates, kubuntu

I am unable to install libgl1-mesa-dri via the terminal or Kubuntu Discover. Attempting to do so via the terminal returns the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gstreamer1.0-gtk3 libaperture-0-0 libbotan-2-19 libgl1-amber-dri libllvm13 libllvm13:i386 libqt5charts5
  libquazip5-1 libtspi1 qml-module-qtcharts
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libgl1-mesa-dri
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
34 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,664 kB of archives.
After this operation, 273 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 214666 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-dri_22.3.0+git2212090959.02d23a79bec~j~mesarc5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (22.3.0+git2212090959.02d23a79bec~j~mesarc5) over (22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_22.3.0+git2212090959.02d23a79bec~j~mesarc5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so', which is also in package libgl1-amber-dri:amd64 21.3.7-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_22.3.0+git2212090959.02d23a79bec~j~mesarc5_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Whereas using Kubuntu Discover returns:

```
Package failed to install
Error while installing package: trying to overwrite &apos;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so&apos;, which is also in package libgl1-amber-dri
```

How should I attempt to fix this?
The system is running Kubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Well having the same issue here too, still looking for a solution

Comment: After some troubleshooting and browsing, [I found this solution to a similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148383/how-to-resolve-dpkg-error-processing-var-cache-apt-archives-python-apport-2-0).
Essentially, you force overwrite the files causing the errors. I suggest you just read the solution because it can explain much better than I can.