# Python 3 Code Error

Tags: python, dpkg

I am new to this. Could someone guide me in the right direction to take care of the error exit status?

```
dpkg: warning: old python3-pip package pre-removal script subprocess returned er
ror exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-pip_22.0.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-pip package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pip.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-pip package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-pip_22.0.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve "dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python-apport\_2.0.1-0ubuntu9\_all.deb"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148383/how-to-resolve-dpkg-error-processing-var-cache-apt-archives-python-apport-2-0)

Comment: `py3clean: not found` suggests that you have removed or mangled the `python3-minimal` package (or a dependency). This can happen for a number of reasons, but most commonly when a human unwisely attempts to "upgrade" the stock version of Python3 on the system to a different version. Restore your system to stock condition (including both `python3` and `python3-minimal` and all their dependencies. Then see if you still have the problem.